# Google's Violation of the Permissions policy

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play-services, android-permissions

Google has removed my from app store and reason they have given is

**Issue: Violation of the Permissions policy**

We only allow apps to access Call Log or SMS data for permitted uses and only to enable the app’s core functionality.

My app is not asking for any kind of call or read sms permission and for reading sms i am using  [alternative implementation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303#alternatives)

My AndroidManifest.xml is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.xyzMobileApp"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- [START fcm_default_icon] -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <!-- [END fcm_default_icon] -->
        <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
        <!-- [END fcm_default_channel] -->

        <!-- Notification Implementation Start -->
        <service
            android:name=".ProductNotificationFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- Notification Implementation End -->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.xyz.xyzMobileApp.AppOnlyDealTracker"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsListener" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.xyz.xyzMobileApp.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.xyz.xyzMobileApp.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/mobile-apps.html" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="m.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/m/mobile-apps.html" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="tv.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/tv/mobile-apps.html" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/track-order/" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="m.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/m/track-order/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is being resolved as I had my older version of my app which has SMS and contact permission in my internal test release. All we have to do is update the latest version of the app in all release i.e in production release, alpha release, beta release, internal test release.

Answer (score 0):

if you removed this SMS permission from your manifest and then upload the app on playstore. Google play still ask you about the fill up the permission form to overcome this issue you have to specify in manifest that these permissions are removed from it, 
like if you add permission asking for reading SMS before than you have to add blow code in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Google removed my app and after a lot of attempts to try to contact them, they confirmed it was because I had an old internal test version, still active, that was using those permissions. After I removed that version, my app was available again in Google Play after 24 hours.